# Creating Spark Row from CSV String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am a new to Spark(Using Scala), I am trying few things in RDD to DF conversion etc.
I have a String variable for Example:

```
val myString = "apple, boy, cat, dog"
```

How can I convert *myString* to `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

I have tried new things like below, but When I am trying to print the length of created row i am getting 1(ONE) where I shall get 4.

```
val row = org.apache.spark.sql.Row.apply(myString)

val row1 = org.apache.spark.sql.Row(myString) 

val row2 = org.apache.spark.sql.Row.fromSeq(Seq(myString.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 3):

the correct way is

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Row.fromSeq(myString.split(','))
//res0: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [apple, boy, cat, dog]
```

where `myString.split(',')` is an `Array[String]` and converted implicitly to `Seq`

and if you want to create a dataframe then

```
val myString = "apple, boy, cat, dog"

val row2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(org.apache.spark.sql.Row.fromSeq(myString.split(','))))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(row2, StructType(Seq(StructField("name1", StringType, true), StructField("name2", StringType), StructField("name3", StringType), StructField("name4", StringType)))).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|name1|name2|name3|name4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|apple| boy | cat | dog |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

where `StructType(Seq(StructField("name1", StringType, true), StructField("name2", StringType), StructField("name3", StringType), StructField("name4", StringType)))` is schema creation.

Comment: Thanks Rameshorg.apache.spark.sql.Row.fromSeq(myString.split(','))
//res0: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [apple, boy, cat, dog] works perfectly....

Comment: @DVN if the answer helped you then you should consider accepting it :0